Not able to delete files from external device like (pendrive, sd card) connected to my device
I am making my own file manager, everything working fine for internal storage. I can rename, move and copy Etc. in the internal storage but when I connect some other storage device with my phone or tablet and try to delete particular file from my own file manager then not getting delete. Even rename is also not working. Although I have given permission of MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Still when I am cheking file.canWrite() then its returning false. I am making my own file manager for android version 7.1.2.
I am using Kotin, Android Studio.
I have given these permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

This code using for deleting the file
private fun deleteFileIfMove() {

    if (typeCopyOrMove.equals(getString(R.string.title_move))){
        val srcFile = File(filePathToBeShare)
        srcFile.delete()
    }

}


"I have given these permissions" -- MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not exist on Android 7.1.2. Please also post the rest of your code for requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at runtime, as a manifest entry is necessary but not sufficient.

@CommonsWare I have requested only "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and because "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " not available for 7.1.2 android version. I checked also read and write external storage permission is given still not able to delete the file.

Have you tried this: Android - R/W to removable SD card?

@Pawel I'm developing my own file manager, so using SAF (Open file manager) wouldn't be ideal. I want to handle all operations within my custom file manager.

@AtulSingh I symphatize with the issue but from what I know you can't use java.File api on removable storage directly unless your device is rooted or you use ADB to forcefully remount SD card with r/w access for non-system user.

@Pawel Thanks for helping. My device is already rooted, and I've tried using ADB as well, but nothing is working.
I have used below code to grant permission of read and write.
adb shell pm grant com.atul.lvm android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
adb shell pm grant com.atul.lvm android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
As you can see below write permission is granted.
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: granted=true
android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
Still not able to modify the file for external storage.

Once again, the issue is not with your app - sd card itself is mounted as read only. You have to look for a solution to "remount sdcard as R/W".

I checked the permissions of SD Card
rk3399_all:/ $ ls -l /storage/1FD2-15F9
ls: /storage/1FD2-15F9/.android_secure: Permission denied
total 1152
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-11 09:56 Alarms
drwxrwx--x 5 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-11 09:58 Android
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-11 09:56 DCIM
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-10 19:11 Download
drwxrwx--x 3 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-11 09:56 Movies
drwxrwx--x 3 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-10-14 18:29 Test1
drwxrwx--x 2 root sdcard_rw 32768 2024-05-22 18:42 Test2
